# How to aggregate duplicate records and sum value using C#

Tags: c#, linq, aggregation

I want to create a list where it holds several agents and the number of calls they make and did it like so:

```
public class Agent
{
    public string Agent_ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Calls { get; set; }

}

var list = new List<Agent>() // To create a list to hold the data
{ 
    new Agent() { Agent_ID = "TK_J", Name = "James", Calls = 10 },
    new Agent() { Agent_ID = "TK_K", Name = "Kurtis", Calls = 10 },
    new Agent() { Agent_ID = "TK_R", Name = "Rebecca", Calls = 5 },
    new Agent() { Agent_ID = "TK_J", Name = "James", Calls = 10 },
    new Agent() { Agent_ID = "TK_R", Name = "Rebecca", Calls = 5 },
    new Agents(){ Agent_ID = "TK_B", Name = "Bobby", Calls = 10 },
};
```

As you can see there will be redundant lines of data. So I want to use C# aggregation function such as group by to sum up the similar agent's number of calls. What I was trying was:

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.Agent_ID).Select(g => new 
{ 
Agent_ID= g.Key, 
Name = */ How do i bring the name here*/, 
Calls = g.Sum(i => i.Calls)});
```

Anyone can help me? Appreciate any help or advice. If there is something wrong teach me how to fix the code. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently grouping by only AgentID.
You'll need to project the fields you require as an anonymous object so they can be available as an `IGrouping<annonymous,Agent>` to the select.
See below.

```
list.GroupBy(i => new {i.Agent_ID, i.Name}).Select(g => new 
{ 
Agent_ID= g.Key.Agent_ID, 
Name = g.Key.Name, 
Calls = g.Sum(i => i.Calls)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Agent_ID` will be synchronized with the Agent's `Name` property, you can also use an aggregate like `First()` to return the the name from any `Agent` record in the group, since all agents in each group will have the same name:

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.Agent_ID)
.Select(g => new Agent // Strong class
{ 
   Agent_ID= g.Key.Agent_ID,
   Name = g.First().Name,
   Calls = g.Sum(i => i.Calls)
})
```

Also, since you seem to be projecting back into the same shape, why not retain and project into the strong class, rather than a new anon class?